# 2 inputs with same classes have different appearances (HTML)

Tags: html

I have made a form with two inputs with the same classes but they have different appearances. They only get the same appearances if I change the type from "email" to "text". Is it a problem with the code or is it HTML5 that does it?

```html
<form action="../../../redirect.html">
<input name="username" id="login-username" class="login-input pure-u-1" type="email" maxlength="96" tabindex="1" aria-required="true" value="" placeholder="Indtast din e-mail" title="Indtast din e-mail" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" required autofocus>

<input name="password" id="login-password" class="login-input pure-u-1" type="password" maxlength="96" tabindex="1" aria-required="true" value="" placeholder="Indtast din adgangskode" title="Indtast din adgangskode" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" required>
<button type="submit" formaction="../../../redirect.html" id="login-signing" class="pure-u-1 pure-button mbr-button-primary" value="Submit" tabindex="1">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what kind of appearances do you aspect?

Comment: The appearances of the inputs/fields of the form!

Comment: i said what kind of appearances! I mean i see no differences between this two input fields.

Comment: That's my question too, there is no difference here, but when I save and try to test it the two input fields look different.

Comment: are you using pure html or you use some library like bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using pure HTML

Comment: can you post your css codes?

Comment: as i see in this css file there is different style for input type "text" and input type "email" and input type "password". so i think your problem is your css file(not html5)

Comment: Can you eventually point it out?

Comment: sorry after i check more i find out that there is no "login-input" in your css and i think you should use "pure-form" instead. am i wrong?

Comment: No you're not wrong, I have used both because I have tried with multiple css-files. "pure-form" works too, but that's also slightly different.

Comment: @DoeJ. To get faster and better help you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in this question you would like to add your html and your css so we can find and understand the issue. Also Consider reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Creating [Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/) also helps.

Comment: @pooyan: Thanks for your replies. If you could summarize the last two comments and post it as an answer I could mark it as final answer.

Comment: you're welcome. i'm glad that i was able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your [css file](https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?/sf/assets/mbrlogin/css/pure-0.3.0-min.css), it seems that it style input's that has class "pure-form" but you have used "login-input". so it seem's that the problem is about how to use your css style not about "HTML5".

this is the correct code:

```
<form action="../../../redirect.html">
<input name="username" id="login-username" class="pure-form pure-u-1" type="email" maxlength="96" tabindex="1" aria-required="true" value="" placeholder="Indtast din e-mail" title="Indtast din e-mail" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" required autofocus>

<input name="password" id="login-password" class="pure-form pure-u-1" type="password" maxlength="96" tabindex="1" aria-required="true" value="" placeholder="Indtast din adgangskode" title="Indtast din adgangskode" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" required>
<button type="submit" formaction="../../../redirect.html" id="login-signing" class="pure-u-1 pure-button mbr-button-primary" value="Submit" tabindex="1">Login</button>
</form>
```